# How to add several new columns if not already present using if statement in geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

new to coding and first time posting so let me know if there is something I haven't included.
I am trying to add new columns to a shapefile. I have a list of columns that are required and sometimes the shapefile will have only some of these. So I need to check which ones are present and add those which are not. I have tried to achieve this using the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
shape = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
add_fields = [['GUI',
           'POLYGON',
           'ORIG_HAB',
           'ORIG_CLASS',
           'EUNIS_L3',
           'HAB_TYPE',
           'VERSION',
           'DET_MTHD',
           'DET_NAME',
           'TRAN_COM',
           'T_RELATE',
           'VAL_COMM',
           'DataAccess',
           'Three_Step',
           'MESH_Confi']]
field_name_list = shape.columns.tolist()
for fieldToAdd in add_fields:
    if fieldToAdd not in field_name_list:
        shape.reindex(shape.columns.tolist() + fieldToAdd, axis=1)
shape.to_file("outputshapefile.shp")
```

When I run the code there are no errors, however the shapefile appears unaltered. I have scoured the forums to see what to try next and that's partly where I found the .reindex. I think that I am not actually adding the new columns but not sure how to do this. If there is anyone can that can point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
add_fields = ['GUI',
           'POLYGON',
           'ORIG_HAB',
           'ORIG_CLASS',
           'EUNIS_L3',
           'HAB_TYPE',
           'VERSION',
           'DET_MTHD',
           'DET_NAME',
           'TRAN_COM',
           'T_RELATE',
           'VAL_COMM',
           'DataAccess',
           'Three_Step',
           'MESH_Confi']
field_name_list = shapefile.columns.tolist()
for fieldToAdd in add_fields:
    if fieldToAdd not in field_name_list:
        #shapefile.reindex(shapefile.columns.tolist().append(fieldToAdd), axis=1)
        shapefile[fieldToAdd]=None
shapefile.to_file("outputshapefile.shp")
```

Please notice that I've changed add_fields to be a 1D instead of 2D (removed outer brackets)
Also I changed the name to shapefile instead of shape, just so to not be confused with a df property.

Comment: That's fantastic thanks a lot, works a treat. Before I tried the attempt originally posted I had something that looked very similar to this solution a part from the =None. When that isn't present I get a key error message with the first column name which is present. What does adding =None  do exactly?

Comment: As we are adding a column,dynamically, as the df is already populate, the None is giving assigning a value to all the elements in the column. Without it, Python wouldn't interpret it as an assignment but a reference to a column that does not exist yet.  The assignment via the = sign acts something like this: "if the column exists, change all its elements to the value at the right of the = sign; if it doesn't exist, create it and populate all its elements with the value at the right of the = sign"